# Bluetooth connection notification

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can I get a bluetooth device's information, available other bluetooth devices and connection notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get bluetooth devices you have to obtain instance of [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) and invoke the `startDiscovery()` method. Also you need to register `ACTION_FOUND` intent. It may be done this way:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBlueToothInfoDiscoveryListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
    {
         BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    }
 }
```

To get information about found device you can use [`getAddress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress%28%29) method .